# VBA_ Getting a Subscript out of Range for paste can't figure out the error

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, subscript

Building this VBA

```
Sub Get_Data()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & import Range")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    
            OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:T30000").Copy
  
         Workbooks("Network\file\Copy of Generic Open Order Report by Sku_Macro - Copy.xlsx").Worksheets(2).Range(A2).Value
        
        
       
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But keep getting an error for the paste or a subscript out of range, it works up till the paste line. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: In ``Copy.xlsx").Worksheets(2).Range(A2).Value``, you must have ``double quotes`` in A2.
What are you really trying to do?

Comment: The error is most likely that there is not a workbook open with that name, especially since it has partial path name in it too. Referencing a workbook like that will not automatically open it to get the value you want. Open it like you did the other one, and reference it using another variable instead of trying to just reference a closed workbook.

Comment: @ElioFernandes I am just trying to copy a range from selected workbook into an existing one. But since the file saves as something new, it helps to open the file path.

Comment: @braX i reduced it down due to workplace safety, I got the link from the info tab on the actual excel sheet. It will copy the information, but for some reason finding the page and pasting is the issue.